# I can print and variable but I cannot set state with it and return Error Undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having this weird issue with Jsx, when I want to print an item of my response it works and I see that it's there and hold a value, however when I try to assign it to state it says it is undefined

```
getUserAsync(this.state.Email)
//Console.log display the data no problem!! typeof String.
        .then(resp =>{ console.log(resp.Hub.Data)}) //Works!!!
        .then((resp => {
          this.setState({
//Below I get ERROR Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Hub' of undefined
            CSQReadings: resp.Hub.Data, //ERRPR???
          });
        }))
```

Any idea why it's doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove one of your .then statements if you aren’t transforming the data or return the value from the first one.

```
getUserAsync(this.state.Email)
      //Console.log display the data no problem!! typeof String.
      .then((resp => {
      this.setState({
            CSQReadings: resp.Hub.Data,
      });
  }))
```

Comment: I always thought I can do that. can you please tell me how it worked under the hood and why it's throwing this error? thanks,

Comment: You can only call .then on a Promise, if you chain .then calls onto each other you need to return something from each one otherwise the next value passed in will be undefined